# Apache Tomcat and IIS on Win Server 2008

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, iis, web-server, tomcat

We have Apache Tomcat running on Windows Server 2008. Is there a problem to install IIS on the same machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to either bind them to different IP addresses or different ports.

If I remember correctly, Tomcat's default port is `8080`? If it's still running on `8080` then they will live side by side quite nicely. Otherwise, you will need to add a 2nd IP address to your Windows installation and bind Tomcat to one and IIS to the other.

Answer (score 2):

This should not be a problem.

There is a module for IIS that will allow you to serve up tomcat through IIS. This way you can use port 80 or 443 for everything.

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/iis.html

There is a slight security risk whenever you host multiple applications on the same server in that a security hole with either application could allow both to be compromised by an attacker.